# Tensorboard Graph Visualization with PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard, torchvision

I'm trying to visualize the graph of a PyTorch model using: https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX

However when I follow instructions on the GitHub README page for the demo-example:

> - Run the demo script: `python demo.py`
> - Use TensorBoard with `tensorboard --logdir runs` (needs to install    TensorFlow)

Most of the options do work - except for the Graph tab. When going there it shows this error message:

> **No graph definition files were found.**
>
> To store a graph, create a `tf.summary.FileWriter` and pass the graph
>   either via the constructor, or by calling its `add_graph()` method. You
>   may want to check out the graph visualizer tutorial.
>
> If you’re new to using TensorBoard, and want to find out how to add
>   data and set up your event files, check out the `README` and perhaps the
>   TensorBoard tutorial.
>
> If you think TensorBoard is configured properly, please see the
>   section of the `README` devoted to missing data problems and consider
>   filing an issue on GitHub.

While the shell outputs these errors:

```
W0817 13:51:54.464755 Thread-1 application.py:272] path /data/plugin/debugger/debugger_grpc_host_port not found, sending 404
W0817 13:51:54.493842 Thread-1 application.py:272] path /data/plugin/debugger/debugger_grpc_host_port not found, sending 404
W0817 13:51:54.507973 Thread-1 application.py:272] path /data/plugin/debugger/debugger_grpc_host_port not found, sending 404
W0817 13:51:54.518329 Thread-1 application.py:272] path /data/plugin/debugger/debugger_grpc_host_port not found, sending 404
W0817 13:51:54.527345 Thread-1 application.py:272] path /data/plugin/debugger/comm not found, sending 404
W0817 13:51:54.536046 Thread-1 application.py:272] path /data/plugin/debugger/comm not found, sending 404
W0817 13:51:54.557759 Thread-1 application.py:272] path /data/plugin/debugger/comm not found, sending 404
W0817 13:51:54.570233 Thread-1 application.py:272] path /data/plugin/debugger/comm not found, sending 404
```

I installed the `tensorboadX` master-branch using:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX
```

*(I Tried also `tensorboardX` version 1.2 before without success)*

I tried switching to different versions but without success,also those which were 'recommended' in combination with `tensorboardX`:

> Tested on anaconda2 / anaconda3, with PyTorch 0.4 / torchvision 0.2 /
>   tensorboard 1.7.0

There are plenty similar issues out there with the same error message stating: `No graph definition files were found.`, but all of which I found where related to Tensorflow itself, not PyTorch.

It seems to me this is just an issue of locating the correct files, but I haven't found any solution yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure you can have a graph definition in pytorch the way you can have one in tensorflow.

Comment: Have you sloved this problem?

Comment: @YuGu No, sorry.